# webapp rendering too small on a mobile screen

Tags: css, materialize

I am building a web application using Materialize as a framework. The fact is that the web application looks good on a computer screen, and even on a browser simulating a mobile screen, but very small on a physical mobile screen.
[image]
The only solution I have found has been to add a media query in the CSS file like this

```
html {
zoom: 2;
```

}

I also included the meta tag just after the head tag
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>`

The result is not bad, but the problem now is that some Materialize pop-ups (such as date pickers or time pickers) and text fields appear cut off
[image]
I'd appreciate any help